# package org.apache.http.entity.mime does not exist

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have been using org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost and HttpGet without a problem.

I need to do a multipart form request but my system doesn't find mime.MultipartEntity even though httpmime.jar is in the same directory tree and it contains MultipartEntity.class

Help!!

TIA, Chet

Comment: I notice that Build.scala has libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.2", but my directory tree is repository/local/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1.2/

Answer (score 5):

I had zero understanding of play! and dependencies, now I know more. I also thought httpmime was part of httpclient, it is not.

I used http://mvnrepository.com/ to get the ivy format for the HttpMime package and entered
it thusly in Build.scala, under application dependencies...

"org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpmime" % "4.2"

I am still unsure why httpclient is already being loaded.